# How to fix 'GNUPlot doesn't plot first point of a 2D contour data, generated by splotting to table

Tags: gnuplot

I have generated a table (splot with "set table 'datafile'" option) in order to obtain a data file of contours. Then, I use the generated datafile, with plot command, in order to generate a 2d graph.
In the datafile there are several contours. 
When I plot the datafile, if I use the command "plot datafile with lines", there is no problem on drawing, but it's no possible to colour differently the various contours.
In order to do that, I use a 'for' loop ("plot for [i=0:*] 'datafile.txt' index i title column(3) with lines"), but, in this case, the first point of the first contour is not draw.

```
reset
set format  xy "%10.5f"
set contour base
set hidden3d
unset surface
set cntrparam level discrete 5
set table "data.txt"
splot 'my_simulated_data.txt'
```

--then if I wrote--

```
reset
set style data lines
plot 'data.txt' with lines
```

--all works fine, but without colour differences in the various contours--

--if I wrote--

```
reset
set style data lines
plot for [i=0:*] 'data.txt' index i title column(3) with lines
```

--there are colour differences between contours but the first point of the first contour is not draw--

Comment: I have seen that, in the second case, gnuplot uses the first row of a contour data (triples of values as contour_abscissa, contour_ordinate, contour_value) as title. Specifically, the third column of the first row. So, the first row is not considered in the graph. Is there a solution in considering the third column as title, without not considering the first row in the graph?

Comment: You could use two separate plot commands, one without the `title` keyword to get the full contour line, and another that doesn't draw anything, but only creates the legend entry. You might also want to take a look at Example 19 on (http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/contours.html).

Comment: @user8152 thank's a lot for your reply. In the example you are linked, it uses a plot with labels. I am sure that this can be adapted to my needs.Wath I want is legends of contour lines as contour values (and not as name of datafile that contains all the contour data blocks, as default), e.g. as the third field of a row of a multiple row block rappresenting a contour.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but perhaps something like `plot for [i=0:*] 'data.txt' index i notitle with lines ls i, for [i=0:*] 'data.txt' u (NaN) index i title column(3) with lines ls i` might work? The first part should plot the contour lines and no legend, and the second part draws nothing but the legend.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The effect is that the first contour is drawn with lines, the second with points instead of lines, but without legends. At the moment, since my software is in vb.NET, and I use GP only as graphic engine, I preprocessed the data file, doubling the first row of a contour block. So, the first row is present twice. The first one is used by GP for the legend, the second and other rows are used for the contour, this time without making holes in the contour due to missing values. It isn't so .....elegant..., it's terrible... but it works fine...